# Stack arrays on specified dimension with arbitrary dimension size

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Consider the following data:

```
data = np.array([[i for i in range(3)] for _ in range(9)])
print(data)
print(f'data has shape {data.shape}')

[[0 1 2]
 [0 1 2]
 [0 1 2]
 [0 1 2]
 [0 1 2]
 [0 1 2]
 [0 1 2]
 [0 1 2]
 [0 1 2]]
data has shape (9, 3)
```

And some parameter, let's call it `history`. The functionality of history is, that it stacks `history` many arrays `[0 1 2]` on the first dimension. As an example, consider 1 iteration of that process with `history=2`

```
history = 2
data = np.array([[[0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2]]])
print(f'data has now shape {data.shape}')
data has now shape (1, 2, 3)
```

Now, let's consider 2 iterations:

```
history = 2
data = np.array([[[0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2]],[[0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2]]])
print(f'data has now shape {data.shape}')
data has now shape (2, 2, 3)
```

This process should be repeated, until the data is fully processed. That implies, that we might lose some data at the end, because `data.shape[0]/history % 2 != 0`.
The final result for `history=2` would thus be

```
     ([[[0, 1, 2],
        [0, 1, 2]],

       [[0, 1, 2],
        [0, 1, 2]],

       [[0, 1, 2],
        [0, 1, 2]],

       [[0, 1, 2],
        [0, 1, 2]]])
```

How can this be done performant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can slice, then reshape:

```
history = 2

out = data[:data.shape[0]//history*history].reshape((-1, history, data.shape[1]))
```

Output:

```
array([[[0, 1, 2],
        [0, 1, 2]],

       [[0, 1, 2],
        [0, 1, 2]],

       [[0, 1, 2],
        [0, 1, 2]],

       [[0, 1, 2],
        [0, 1, 2]]])
```

Comment: what is `a`? Otherwise exactly what I need

Comment: Sorry, it's `data`